# What can I do when i found an unanswered question interesting, but not enough to spend reputation on a bounty?

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement, bump

I found a question slightly interesting, but not so much as I'm ready to lose reputation by placing a bounty on it. Not that I care so much about rep, but, well not totally indifferent about it either.

I read in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82295) that editing it to bump it is considered as a abuse of the system.

Can't really improve it, and no idea how to answer it either.

Is there something I can do? Include it in this post for the meta effect?

Comment: so..... one thing I will say: if it's not your question, don't try to control the meta effect on it. Would you feel good if the OP of that question lost rep because you link a less than stellar question and the meta effect gets it downvoted?

Comment: You've already found the three ways - a bounty, an edit, or the meta effect. Only the first one is considered acceptable. So... either let it go, or be ready to spend at least 50 rep points.

Comment: You could try posting links to the question off-site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also:

- Use the share link to promote the question on social media.
- Share with people in real life.
- Discuss it in a relevant chat room (assuming the room's rules allow for it).
- Up vote it (a positive score will help people searching for unanswered questions find it).

Answer (score 7):

You can upvote it to indicate you think it's interesting (and also an otherwise acceptable, on topic, clear, etc. question).

You should not be posting questions on meta just to try to get people to upvotes it, no.  It's not likely to have the desired effect, and it's not an acceptable course of action regardless.

You're also welcome to share a link to the question to any offsite locations that you want.  Make sure to post it in places where it would be welcome and likely seen by people who would want to see it though, else (like posting on meta just for upvotes) it may have the opposite of the desired effect.